# How Much water can a tank hold?

Tags: volume

At Sonia’s house there are two water tanks. One tank can hold $500$ litres more than the smaller tank. When the smaller tank is $2/3$ full it holds as much water as half the larger tank. What is the capacity of the largest tank?

Comment: Let the volume of the largest tank be $x$, and of the smaller be $y$. Can you rewrite the first and second conditions in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $b,s$ be the max capacity of the larger, and smaller tanks. Then:
$b = s+500, \dfrac{2s}{3} = \dfrac{b}{2}$. Substitute $s+500$ for $b$ in the second equation to get: $\dfrac{2s}{3} = \dfrac{s+500}{2}\implies s = 1,500, b = 2,000$ liters respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Let $V$ be the volume of the large tank and $v$ be the volume of the smaller tank. Then from the problem, you can derive that
$$V=v+500$$
$$\frac{1}{2}V=\frac{2}{3}v$$
Can you solve this system of equations?